# Orbeon - dynamic XML in POST request body

Tags: orbeon

I need help with body of POST request. I need send XML whitch can be dynamically assemble. Not only putting values in elements.
I work with Orbeon 2021.1.2 PE. There are two cases I came across when connecting to my backend and they are quite similar:

1] There is a array in the request where its length is based on the data in the form.

When using a request template:

```
<SendAction>
  <IDs>
    <ID></ID>
  </IDs>
</SendAction>
```

You can simply put a value using `//ID` and the result is this:

```
<SendAction>
  <IDs>
    <ID>AAA</ID>
  </IDs>
</SendAction>
```

But I would need a request when the number of `<ID>` is N like:

```
<SendAction>
  <IDs>
    <ID>AAA</ID>
    <ID>BBB</ID>
    <ID>CCC</ID>
  </IDs>
</SendAction>
```

2] The request again has a dynamically long array but I need put entire object. E.g:

```
 <Wheapons>
    <Weapon>
        <LicenseNumber>123456789</LicenseNumber>
        <Name>Gun A</KindOfWeapon>
        <Category>0</Category>
    </Weapon>
    <Weapon>
        <LicenseNumber>987654321</LicenseNumber>
        <Name>Gun B</KindOfWeapon>
        <Category>0</Category>
    </Weapon>
<Wheapons>
```

I hope you get my point. Data in second example I have in `fr:dataset()` and in Repeated Grid too (it is output of diferent endpoint). I tried to insert whole blocks of XML, but Orbeon always encode the characters in xml ('<' to "& lt;" and '>' to "& gt;") and therefore the request is not processed. This behavior is basically good, because I'm trying something like XML injection. But I achieve the same bad result when using the `xf:element()` function. Is this problem solvable by some funcitons or I'm complete wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Hi David, in what context are you trying to put together that XML? How would the service be called? Are you in a form you created with Form Builder? Are you using the Services & Actions? The XML would only depend on data in a dataset, not on information entered by users in the form? -Alex

Comment: I need build POST HTTP requests.
First example is when user wanna send same message to more address (here is represeanted by element ID). Number and value of IDs comes from form (repeted grid). 

Second example is situation where form read data from one system (HTTP GET), show on form (repeted grid) only for approval not for making changes and then send all of them to another system.
Problem is that I know structure of data but length is always dynamic. So i cant use simple POST XML body.

Comment: I'm using standart Form Builder and yes, I'm using Services & Actions. Easy solution is cut XML to objects and send separatly but it will be very slow. Request overhead will be terrible huge...

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to do this just with the Form Builder UI. You could do this with some XForms that would need to code "by hand", and attach to the form using a `oxf.fr.detail.model.custom.*.*` property (see [Custom model](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/custom)). Would something along those lines work for you?

Comment: Hi David, did you get a chance to look into using a custom XForms model for this? or is this something that wouldn't work for you? -Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that your form has a repeated grid, and that you would like to call a service POSTing XML to that service based on the values of fields inside a repeated grid. This isn't something that you can do with the Services & Actions in Form Builder; currently, those only let you send individual values to a service. So, instead, you'll need to write that logic in XForms. At a high level:

- The XForms will go in a custom model ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/custom)), i.e. a separate file on the server with your XForms logic.
- In that XForms, you write an event handler, for an event of your choosing, and you will dispatch that event from a process, in your `properties-local.xml`, with `xf:dispatch()` ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-xforms#xf-dispatch)).
- Your XForms custom model also declares an `xf:submission`, to do the actual POST, an instance, with the data to be posted, and in the event handler you populate the instance from the data in your grid, and run the submission.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! It makes more sense to me now. Your previous comment confused me a bit (I'm so good in XForms) and I try for a long time possibility of changing my backend somehow. I'll discuss it with a colleague, try something and write response. Thanks

Comment: Got it David, and if you decide to implement this with XForms, even if doing something along the lines of what I described above shouldn't be too complicated, I wouldn't be surprised if you find it to somewhat of a challenge without experience in XForms (just as it would be doing something with any new technology!), so feel free to ask questions here on Stack Overflow if you encounter any problem with that. And good luck! -Alex

Answer (score 0):

I find simple and dummy solution but @avernet was right. If you want generic function for whole project you must write own custom model.
Here is my snippet:

```
    <xf:instance id="test_service-template">
        <item>
            <id/>
        </item>
    </xf:instance>
    
    <xf:instance id="test_service-instance">
        <values>
            <item>
                <id>123</id>
            </item>
        </values>
    </xf:instance>
    
      <xf:instance id="test_service-resposne-service-instance">
        <response/>
    </xf:instance>
    
    <xf:submission id="test_service-submission" resource="/fr/service/custom/orbeon/echo"
                   ref="instance('test_service-instance')"
                   method="post"
                   serialization="application/xml"
                   mediatype="application/xml"
                   replace="instance"
                   instance="test_service-resposne-service-instance"/>
    <xf:action id="test_action-binding">
        <xf:action event="DOMActivate" ev:observer="control-2-control" if="true()">
            <xf:insert context="xxf:instance('test_service-instance')" ref="values"
                       origin="xxf:instance('test_service-template')"/>
            <xf:setvalue ref="xxf:instance('test_service-instance')/values/item[1]/id" value="'321'"/>
            <xf:send submission="test_service-submission"/>
        </xf:action>
    </xf:action>
```

If you don't use Services & Actions in Form Builder you can send your own instance as body of request (`test_service-instance`).
Before submission you can simple build this instance (by `insert` and `setvalue`). You can put then somewhere else in form (for example under trigger). Response of submission can have own instance too.